# Is there a way to find a site by an image they link to?

Tags: search, url

I have the URL for an image that I downloaded, and I'm trying to locate the site that linked to it.

E.g. http://12345.blob.windows.net/random/abc123.jpg

The image hosting site is windows.net.

Is there any way to find out which site owns this image? Is there a way to search sites by their HTML to find out who links to it?

Comment: "Own" as in the copyright holder?

Comment: @iglvzx In this instance, I simply ment the site that had uploaded the image, or was using it. They are using an image hosting service so I couldn't determine the sites url from the image's url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse Image search engines like [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com) can be used to find this.

"TinEye is a reverse image search engine. It finds out where an image came from, how it is being used, if modified versions of the image exist, or if there is a higher resolution version"

I used one image url on it and [results](http://www.tineye.com/search/22ca09f6f17e3a2626ae2c7269abbea6573c6034/) showed the 50 sites where it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Google also has the ability to upload images as a search entry. Go to Google image search and click on the small photograph icon.

See also: http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html

Answer (score 1):

Does the operator **[link](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#link)** from Google web search help?

> link: The query link:URL shows pages that point to that URL. For
>   example, to find pages that point to Google Guide’s home page, enter:
>
> [ link:www.googleguide.com ]
>
> Note: According to Google’s documentation, “you cannot combine a link:
>   search with a regular keyword search.”
>
> Also note that when you combine link: with another advanced operator,
>   Google may not return all the pages that match. The following queries
>   should return lots of results, as you can see if you remove the -site:
>   term in each of these queries.
>
> Find links to the Google home page not on Google’s own site.
>
> [ link:www.google.com -site:google.com ]
>
> Find links to the UK Owners Direct home page not on its own site.
>
> [ link:www.www.ownersdirect.co.uk -site:ownersdirect.co.uk ]