# Is there a way to search for pages that display an image if you have the image URL?

Tags: search, images, url

Is there a way to search for pages that display an image if you have the image URL?

Reverse image search is not useful for this as the image is far from unique. It is not the image contents that are interesting here but the specific image URL. I do not have access to the server logs so there is also no chance of getting anything out of that.

[Is there a way to find a site by an image they link to?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-site-by-an-image-they-link-to) is related but not exactly the same. [This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26440/54047) on that question comes closest but does not appear to work for displayed images.

Comment: Are you looking for webpages that use the exact image URL instead of webpage that use similar image (but NOT exact image URL)?

Comment: @IvanChau The former. Exact image URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Nerdydata](http://nerdydata.com/), which is a search engine for indexing webpage source code.

You should be able to search for web pages that use the exact image URL, if any.
Paste URL into the search box.

[Nerdydata Image Search: Locate an image with the full image URL](https://search.nerdydata.com/images)

<sub>Technical details: It may not work if the image is linked in CSS file instead of img tag.</sub>

Comment: Doesn't seem to work very well though. It's not returning any results for a few random images I tried off of Google Images.

Comment: Google Images look for similar image based on the characteristics of pasted image while Nerdydata finds if any website directly link to the original image. IMO, webpage owners should host the image on their server but not [hotlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlink) the image. That explains the few results.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want something like this: [How do I find the earliest / original instance of an image on the web?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26846/26981). Reverse image search engine do contains the link which include the image and possibly the series of image.

Comment: I was thinking that if Google know of the image I should get at least one hit on NerdyData too, but so far I haven't found any hits.